# Insert into two tables simultaneously, using **ID**(primary key, auto increment) from first table to store data on second table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need to store data on two tables simultaneously.
with first table **window** having columns (ID, start_time, stop_time, message) and second table **windowClients** having columns (ID, Clients).

**window**

| ID | start_time | stop_time | message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022-12-03 15:13:00 | 2022-10-03 15:13:00 | hello |
| 101 | 2022-10-15 13:10:00 | 2022-10-03 15:13:00 | test |

**windowClients**

| ID | Clients |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 443 |
| 100 | 147 |
| 100 | 600 |
| 101 | 556 |
| 101 | 555 |

How should i insert the following data in both of two tables at the same time:

```
ID         : 102
start_time : 2022-12-25 11:11:00 
stop_time  : 2022-10-26 11:11:00 
message    : Holiday timeout
Clients    : 256, 727, 600, 535
```

Comment: With 2 connections? One `INSERT`ing into the table `window` and the other into `windowClients`. I'm not sure what you're *really* asking here.

Comment: when inserting in table **window** ID is auto generated. i want to insert 'Clients' into **windowClients** with that same ID.

Comment: Then you *can't* do them simultaneously; you'll need to `INSERT` into `window` first and then `windowClient`. It's ***impossible*** do to something simultaneously if one action depends on the completion of the other.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a transaction by starting and ending your two INSERT statements with `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT` respectively:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/t_sql/t_sql_transactions.htm

That will provide you the atomicity and consistency you'd want.  If it fails, neither executes and the database state will be updated at the same time.

Comment: i know Trans but how do i fetch **ID** from **window**  and insert into **windowClient** before running the second insert command?

Comment: Your comment re auto-increment keys changes the approach.  As mentioned above, 'output' or a stored procedure will have to be used here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74737331/insert-into-2-different-data-to-2-table-at-the-same-time-using-first-datas-id

Comment: but i'm using Mariadb.